# List all vectors orthogonal to v <15, 20>

Tags: vector-spaces

I have this assignment question which i don't understand. Here is the question:

> Consider the vector $v=(15, 20)$. List all the vectors that are
>   orthogonal to $v$, but of the same length as $v$. You must obtain these
>   vectors by solving a system of equations. Remeber that if $a^2=b$, then
>   $a = +-\sqrt{(b)}$

I have basics on how to check if a vector is orthogonal and how to find the size of the vector and all that stuff

What I don't understand is what **exactly** is the question asking? Is it asking for a general equation? A guide or explanation on what is asked could help me.

---

EDIT:
I got 2 equations based on the requirements. They are:
$x^2+y^2=625$
and
$15x+20y=0$
Am i supposed to solve this to find a value for x and y? If yes how can do it by forming an augmented matrices since in this course we are learning how to solve a system using matrices.

In other words. How can I form an matrix since x^2 and y^2 are not linear?

Answer (score 1):

Let the vector be $(x,y)$  You should get one equation from the fact that the length is the same as $(15,20)$ and a second from the dot product telling you it is orthogonal to $(15,20)$  This gives two equations in two unknowns.  There will be two solutions.

Comment: hi thanks for helping me, if you dont mind, could you help me out with the edited part?

Comment: I don't know how to use an augmented matrix with quadratic equations.

Answer (score 1):

It is asking for you to state exactly which vectors are orthogonal to $v$ and have the same length as $v$. The third and fourth sentences you quote are only hints on how to solve the problem.

Explicitly, given a vector $w = (x,y)$, write down what it means for $w$ to be orthogonal to $v$ and what it means for $w$ to have the same length as $v$. This will give you two equations in terms of $x$ and $y$, which you can then solve to obtain all possible vectors $w$ satisfying these conditions.

Comment: hi thanks, if you don't mind, could you help me out with the edited part?

Comment: The resulting system of equations isn't linear, so you can't solve it using an augmented matrix. You can use a more elementary method: use the equation $15x+20y=0$ to express $y$ in terms of $x$ (or vice versa, if you prefer) and substitute into the other equation.